# Find the radius of convergence of the series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Find the radius of convergence of

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n!z^{2n}}{(1+n^2)^n} .$$ Actual trouble is finding the limit applying Ratio test. Please help.

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 3):

Note that the coefficient of $z^{2n}$ is $\frac{n!}{(1+n^2)^n}$, so we want to compute 
$$\frac1R=\limsup \sqrt[2n]{\frac{n!}{(1+n^2)^n}} $$
But $$\sqrt[2n]{(1+n^2)^n}=\sqrt{1+n^2}> n $$
and 
$$ \sqrt[2n]{n!}=\sqrt{\sqrt[n]{n!}}<\sqrt{\frac{1+2+\ldots+n}n}=\sqrt{\frac{n+1}2} $$
by the arithmetic-geometric inequality.
So 
$$\frac1R=\limsup \sqrt[2n]{\frac{n!}{(1+n^2)^n}}\le\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{n+1}2}}{n}=0$$
and $R=\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\frac{n!z^{2n}}{(1+n^2)^n}\sim_\infty\frac{n!z^{2n}}{n^{2n}}:=u_n$$
and by ratio test
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}=0<1 $$
hence the radius is $R=\infty$.